# Save all helm input history even if I cancelled the helm command at the end

Tags: helm

Helm only saves user input history that was not cancelled.  Could I include those cancelled input to history?  I sometimes cancel some useful inputs because I just wanted to have a peek.  I would like to keep those inputs in history so that I can re-search again quickly.

Comment: FWIW, [Icicles has a separate history](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_History_Enhancements#Which) for things you used for completion and things you finally entered (e.g. `RET`) in the minibuffer. You can use `C-l` (`icicle-retrieve-previous-input`) and `C-L`, (`icicle-retrieve-next-input`) to cycle among your past completion inputs. Perhaps Helm now has something similar.

Comment: I think this would be a mess of a feature. Maybe you'd get your job done by accepting the completion and then just popping the mark to get back to where you started?